# Truncate content to the first paragraph with Smarty

Tags: smarty, tiki-wiki

On an article website using smarty template, I need to truncate the main content to create teaser. I can truncate by char but first paragraph length is totally unknown from article to article.
I want something smarter that just show the first paragraph:

Content:

```
This is my first paragraph and I want to display this and only this.

This the rest of the content and it is very long with a lot of words...
```

Teaser:

```
This is my first paragraph and I want to display this and only this.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So is the text to truncate wiki syntax or html at this point? If it's wiki the you should be able to do a search for \n\n using `strpos` php function *(add it to the smarty functions in the security control panel if it's not one of the allowed ones already)*. Then you can do a `substr` function on the text and add the "..." or whatever after it.
If it's html then a `preg_replace` would probably be the best approach - something like

```
{preg_replace('/^.*?<\/p>/mis','$1"',$content)}...
```

...might just work (untested, sorry ;)
HTH

Comment: Thanks for pointing me the right direction.  

Using this I could solve the second part of my question, how to hide the first paragraph from my content after removing the multiline flag:  
 
`{*Remove the first paragraph*}`  
`{preg_replace('/^.*?<\/p>/is','',$content)}`  

However my attempt to display ONLY the first paragraph failed.  
The code you post above shows only " three times (my content has 3 paragraph)

Removing the multiline flag show only one " and the other paragraph. 
`{preg_replace('/^.*?<\/p>/is','$1"',$content)}`